# 'React/RCTDefines.h' file not found after upgrading from 0.59 to 0.61

Tags: ios, react-native

we just upgraded our react native app from react-native 0.59 to 0.61 but now I get a really strange error in XCode which I don't know how to solve.

It seems to have something to do with the library https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob which we use to download files from the server to the app. According to their README.md, they support react-native version 0.60 and above but it doesn't seem to work.

The error seems to be origniating from `node_modules/rn-fetch-blob/ios/RNFetchBlob/RNFetchBlob.h:22:`

[image]

Anyone who can support us in solving this issue? Thanks in advance for your support!

Answer (score 1):

Just to point out one fact, RN0.61 has removed React.xcodeproj. This is a [breaking changes](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2019/09/18/version-0.61) we should expect during the upgrade.

**Update:** managed to find a '[workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58373425/react-rctdefines-h-file-not-found-rn0-61/58398989#58398989)' for now.

Answer (score 0):

you ought to use version number 0.10.8 of rn-fetch-blob.

if you still have same problem, you should check [this link](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/Manually-Link-Package) about [manually link package.](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/Manually-Link-Package)